# Flexible File Writer User defined variables and headers not in tab

Tags: file, csv, jmeter-plugins, writer

I have a CSV file from which I am reading parameters.

I want using Flexible File Writer to write the extracted values I am able to write Available Fields but I want to write the variables I am reading from CSV as well as extracted response but extracted values are not being written also the headers and values are written in the single cell I want those to be written in separate cells.

[image: WrittenCSVFileData]

Comment: Just out of the box functionality and only added extra user defined variable ShowingNoOfProducts at the end

Comment: Hi This is what I have in File Writer Config if this will help  In the File Header -- I have : URL responseTime latency sentBytes receivedBytes isSuccessful responseCode ShowingNoOfProducts   --- In the Record Each sample as is  : URL|\t|responseTime|\t|latency|\t|sentBytes|\t|receivedBytes|\t|isSuccessful|\t|responseCode|\t|ShowingNoOfProducts#0|\r\n